# I need to return values based on what is written on a text field

Tags: oracle-apex

Ok, I have to build a page where the user inputs the registration number of the employee, and then after clicking on a button, it should pop a table with the roles in which this person has access. How can I configure a text field in a way that selects something in the database and then returns this informaton into a table?

I tried using a dynamic action but I actually didn't have any result

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood it:

- create a page item, let's call it `P1_REGNUM`

  - if you don't want users to *type* that value manually, set it to e.g. **select list** (or popup) item, write a List of Values query that returns list of valid values
  - also, set that item to **submit** the page (so that you wouldn't even need a button)

    - if you want to have a button, OK - have it; let it submit the page as well
- create report region (pick between classic and interactive report)
- use `P1_REGNUM` in its `where` clause, e.g.

  ```
  select regnum, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth
  from employees
  where regnum = :P1_REGNUM
  ```
- put `P1_REGNUM` into *items to submit* region property
- that's it; run the page, enter (or select) registration number and report will fetch data related to value that is in `P1_REGNUM` item